# Quasi-static and Poly-tropic processes

Tags: thermodynamics

can we say all quasi-static processes are poly-tropic process?. since in a quasi-static process a smooth graph can be drawn between pressure and volume therefore, can we conclude that all quasi-static process are poly-tropic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a polytropic process is one in which $PV^n=C$. Even for an ideal gas ($PV=NRT$), $P, V$ and $T$ are independent variables, so you can have a quasistatic process in which $T$ is an arbitrary function of $P$. 
For instance, 
let us chose $T=\cos(P)$. In such a case the relationship between $P$ and $V$ is not polytropic: $PV/\cos(P)=C$.

Comment: A physical example of a quasi-static but not polytropic process: a gas-filled piston-cylinder arrangement in which the piston is held down by a spring. Slowly heating or cooling the gas is a quasi-static process, but on a P-V diagram it appears as a straight line ($P = kV$). Assuming that $k$ isn't zero or infinity, there is no way of writing this as a function $PV^n = C$.

Comment: How did you conclude that this 'piston-cylinder arrangement' undergoes quasi-static process (or shows slow cooling/heating)? Is this an assumption? Had there not been a spring, the process would've been irreversible right?